# How can we differentiate between a responsive web app vs progressive web app?

Tags: javascript, web, progressive-web-apps

What the difference between two types ? Is all progressive web app can also be said responsive web app or vice-versa ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Responsive web apps and progressive web apps are not directly related or fall in one category. However to describe :

1. Responsive Website is the one whose interface is optimized for all screen resolutions. Not all 
   responsive websites are progressive web apps. And may not even be close to a PWA.
2. A Progressive web app is a web app that gives the user a native feel and is embedded with offline working capabilities, push notifications and much more. Here is the [guide about PWA](https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/). All PWAs should be responsive.